# extending classes in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a user management script that I plan on porting to codeigniter.

```
Login extends Integration

              Integration extends Generic

                                  Generic extends Connect
```

`Login` inherits `Integration`, and `Integration` inherits `Generic` .etc. So I can access functions in `Generic` via `Login`. Is it necessary that I make `Login extends CI_Model`, and if so, how to I integrate the other classes, so that I maintain the same functionality, when calling login via `$this->load->models()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI_Model allows you to work directly with the DB object without importing it yourself - that's about the only thing it does. If your Login library has no need for those functions or you don't intend to port it as a "CI library", you can simply load it as a normal library with:

```
$this->load->library();
```